# Unable to locate package libmysql++-dev

Tags: mysql

```
root@avidgamers:~/warcraft/aG-HostbotRU/ghost# apt-get install libmysql++-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmysql++-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libmysql++-dev'
root@avidgamers:~/warcraft/aG-HostbotRU/ghost#
```

OS: Ubuntu LTS 12.04 64Bit

I've been able to install this package on numerous other servers, but it isn't downloading this package on this new server. I can, however, download and install other packages that I need. It may not make a difference, but the server is located in Moscow, Russia.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, run `apt-get update`. If you get any errors, edit your post and include the output. If you don't get errors, try installing the package again.
2. If that doesn't work, check if you have universe repositories enabled: Open your software center and place your mouse cursor on the top of your desktop. In the menu that appears, click Edit >> Software sources. In the first tab (Ubuntu Software), check if universe is enabled. If it's not, then enable it and run `apt-get update` again and try installing the package again.
3. If that doesn't work too, you should probably try another mirror. Follow the instructions in 2 and change the "Download from" combobox. You can see a list of the mirrors with information on how updated it is here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors. That should help you choose one. Remember to choose one that's near you location.

If nothing of this works, edit your post including the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 2):

[The `libmysql++-dev` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libmysql%2b%2b-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) is in the [universe repository component](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu). My guess is that it's not found because Universe isn't enabled on your system. So **[enable the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)**, and you should be able to install it.

In general, when a package won't install even when it seems like you're doing all the right things, it's useful to make sure it's really available for the version of Ubuntu you're running, and what repository provides it. To do that, you can search for the package at http://packages.ubuntu.com/.

It's possible this is *not* the cause of the problem, of course. In that case, I recommend expanding your question with information about what you saw when you checked to see if Universe was enabled, as well as with [the information requested by GabrielF](https://askubuntu.com/a/405955/22949).

Comment: Why is this CW?

Comment: @Seth I felt like making it CW. :) ...Actually, the reason is that when I started writing it, it seemed like it was a lot like a "possible duplicate" comment, just more suitable as an answer. It would be fine as a regular, non-CW post, but I didn't feel any need to uncheck the box. If I had ended up expanding it with lots of subheadings and shell commands and screenshots with hand-drawn circles, I would've gone ahead and made it non-CW. Of course, as a CW post, people should feel free to treat it like any other CW, and be even more willing than usual to edit it for improvement ...if they wish.